# WCF Service call to multiple rows. How to architecture it?

Tags: wcf, performance, architecture, loops

Let's say I have a scenario where I have a Service that is responsible for retrieving the price of a single product given the ID and another Service that gives me the current stock position of it.

It's okay when I'm looking only at one product, but what about a list page where I have 60 products? What should I do in this case? Call the service product by product to retrieve it's current price and stock position?

I think this would be extremely slow and cost a lot of resources. But what could I do to make it look good and at the same time have performance?

Currently we have these information in the database in a column next to the product. These price and stock columns are updated by a sql service that updates it when is necessary so when I need to grab the value for a lot of products at the same time I just need to select two columns more. It's really fast, but right now we have some more systems in need of this information and I would like to transform all these stuff in a service.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could always have multiple service methods:

- the one you already have, to retrieve a single product, and the price for a single product
- create a new service method which would take a list of product ID's, and return a list of product objects - or a new DTO (data-transfer object) that holds product and price

This way, you could keep your current users happy, and also do something to make batch requests work more efficiently.

Comment: I thought of that marc_s, but it doen't seems to me very "SOA", you know what I mean? I know it's odd, but it doesn't look good. Maybe my mindset is not correct.

But let's say I'll do it. After calling the batch service I would have to merge the data returned from service with the rest of the data I have and it does not smells good too.

How it sounds to you? Thanks a lot, man.

Comment: I don't agree - either way, if you have to check the price and product info for 60 products, it'll be a loop or something. I don't see how that extra service method should "not be SOA"......

Comment: I know it makes sense, but I just don't like it...eeheheheh I guess it's my mindset. What would you say about the merge? It's how you would do? Thanks, again.

Comment: I don't totally understand your "merge" question part.... merge where and why and what?? Can't you make your service return all the bits of information you need? If not - well, yes, then you have to merge that information from the service with other information somehow - that's raelly not dependent on WCF or your service design....

Answer (score 0):

Can your service method take an array of IDs?  And return an array of values?  That way if you want one record your array only has 1 item, if you want more, you just populate the array with multiple values?

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553267/design-parameter-decision ?